# Reasons why POST won't work when moving CodeIgniter site to another domain

Tags: php, codeigniter, post

I'm using CodeIgniter next to a Wordpress install.

So, I've got this site that I developed on one server. That works fine. I've moved it to another server and actually hacked it up to make another site which also works fine.

So now I've moved that site to a third server and my forms aren't posting right, or something.
They are submitting to the correct controller but when I `var_dump $_POST` or `$this->input->post('anyvariable')` Im getting empty arrays and falses.

I'm banging my head against the wall over this. I'm thinking maybe it's a .htaccess problem as nothing else has changed from the other sites.

Can anyone suggest a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so i turns out that I was getting a 301 redirect when I submitted the form because in my codeigniter config file i didn't put http://www.mysite.com but instead had http://mysite.com.

Thats why my post data was being cleared but I was still reaching the correct controller to do the var_dump.

I noticed this after checking the Net tab in firebug.

I should have realized this sooner but i was coding for 12 hours already when I got to this point because I needed to make a deadline.

Answer (score 1):

In the config file check all settings and especially $config['base_url']. Maybe when you use `form_open(method_name)`, form doesn't redirect correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're not posting any data to the page. Are you sure the URL is correct, and you're working on the right file? Perhaps add a print at the top to make *sure* you're editing the right file, and posting to the right one as well. Also, consider using wireshark or something to see the raw POST request, to see if the data is in fact there. Not sure what else to tell you at this point.

Comment: well when I submit the form its going to the controller its supposed to because that where I'm print/var_dumping the post array at.  verified the html via firbug.